# Wiring an ExecutorService in with Spring factory-method

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple class that has a property called "executor" in which I'd like to wire in an `ExecutorService`, with spring 3.0. I followed the documentation which states you simply use the factory class (in this case `Executors`) and supply factory-method to create your service. However, when I try to wire the resulting bean into my class, it seems that spring thinks the class type is java.lang.String instead of ExecutorService.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I seem to be correct if I look at the documentation, but perhaps I need to somehow indicate the resulting class of calling the factory method?

Here's the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService] for property 'executor': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

With this configuration:

```
<bean id="taskManager" class="examples.TaskManager">
    <property name="executor">
        <idref local="executorService" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="executorService" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" 
  factory-method="newSingleThreadExecutor" 
  destroy-method="shutdownNow" />
```

and this class:

```
public class TaskManager {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    public ExecutorService getExecutor() {
        return executor;
    }

    public void setExecutor(ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try simple `ref` attribute instead of `idref`:

```
<bean id="taskManager" class="examples.TaskManager">
    <property name="executor" ref="executorService" />
</bean>
```

and see [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?14211-Difference-between) that the meaning of `idref` is passing the referenced bean's **name** (as a `String`) to the property.

Oh, and here's the [Spring doc itself](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html):

> **The idref element**
>
> The idref element is simply an error-proof way to pass the id (string
>   value - not a reference) of another bean in the container to a
>    or  element.

Comment: Darn, having changed that after failing to wire the bean anonymously, I didn't realise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**use ref instead of idref** idref returns the string name of the passed argument

```
<bean id="taskManager" class="examples.TaskManager">
    <property name="executor" ref="executorService" />
  </bean>
```

**The idref element in spring framework**

The idref element allow you to pass the bean id (which is the string value not the reference) of another bean in the container to a  or . In the given example it is clearly shown how pass the bean id to another bean and also display the bean id

refer http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/ioc/springidrefelement.html

**Reference Injection**

In the reference injection one bean definition is injected to another. For reference injection you use the constructor-arg or property's ref attribute instead of the value attribute.

refer http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/ioc/springreferenceinjection.html

Comment: Please don't use roseindia links to illustrate your point. Their stuff is inaccurate and misleading. There are other, better sources.

Comment: @skaffman thanks for the information next time i will take care about this